# changing img src in javascript by click on button

Tags: javascript, html

this is my code:
I want to change the img src by clicking on the  button and add one to the counter that change the next photo again But only the first photo is displayed !
and
I have 8 img in this path : images/slides/writing${0-7};

```js
slider = () =>{
    let i=0;
      let slides = document.getElementById('slides').getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
    slides.src = `images/slides/writing${i}.jpg` ; 
    i++
    
   
}
```

```html
  
<section id="slides">
        <picture>
          <img src="" alt="Slide img">
          <input type="button" value="change" onclick="slider()">
      </picture>
 </section>
```

Comment: You reset `i = 0` every time `slider()` is called (and it's a new variable every time because you declare it locally with `let`). Move this line outside of the function: `let i=0;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are always setting `i` to 0 inside the function, just make it global and make sure it doesn't exceed `7`:

```
let i=0;
slider = () =>{
    if(i==8) i=0;
    let slides = document.getElementById('slides').getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
    slides.src = `images/slides/writing${i}.jpg` ; 
    i++
}
```